# Use of value vs variable in performance 

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
select *
from table1 t1
where
  t1.somedate between UDF(date1) and UDF(date2)
```

UDF: user defined function

This `UDF(date1)` and `UDF(date2)`, will it be evaluated for each and every row of `t1`.

This degrades performance.

2nd option I tried

```
declare @a datetime, @b datetime
set @a=UDF(date1)
set @b=UDF(date2)
select *
    from table1 t1
    where
      t1.somedate between @a and @b
```

Even this is taking a long time.

What could be the reason, and what could be the work around.

if i write

```
select *
    from table1 t1
    where
      t1.somedate between date1 and date2
```

its very fast. takes around 3 sec. queries above take 2-3 min.

Comment: Your second option is the correct method. Could you share your UDF code? Have you checked the execution plans to make sure it is UDF taking the time and you are not just missing an index on the table, etc

Comment: Its sure that UDF is taking time, as the 3rd query is very fast, i have indexe on somedate column

Comment: could u please tell me if udf will be evaluated every single time for a row, in the 1st query.

Comment: First of all why you need UDF here?

Comment: somedate lies in timezone x. date1, date2 lie in timezone y. to compare x with y i need to convert date1,date2 to timezone x. thats where i am using the udf.

Comment: Yes it will be evaluated for every row in first query. Need UDF code because that is where you have the performance problem you are asking us to help you with

Comment: what is the exact type of `somedate`? Is it `DATETIME`, `DATE`, `DATETIME2`, `VARCHAR`, which is it?

Comment: @Pete:I do not have the UDF code, its a proprietary code hidden from us.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think that using variables instead of UDFs will not get you an improvement in the performance, as the udf should be deterministic. So it will get calculated only once.

Second, do you have an index on the somedate field? if you do not, put one. If you have, you might check how much data you get and if you have networking problems.

You should check to see the query plan, it will show you better what is going on there.

Comment: somedate has an index! will udf be evaluated every single time (1st query)

Comment: Actually, using of variables instead of UDF's in queries can help optimizer to choose appropriate indexes.

Comment: Well I said that the UDF 'should' be deterministic. I rarely saw non deterministic udfs. In case that the udf is marked as deterministic, then the optimizer will treat it as a variable.

Comment: my UDF is deterministic, its udf(datetime, fromtimezone, totimezone).

Comment: Then you can use it in your query without worrying on penalties.

Comment: The best answer you can get is searching in the query plan.